# Get rid of automatic quotes CSV file

Tags: python, load, save, quotes, file-format

I've made a dictionary with a tuple as key. The dictionary should look like this after i load it:

```
dictionary = {("key1", "key2"): "value"}
```

The problem is that when i save it into an CSV file it adds unnecessary quotes so it looks like this:

```
dictionary = {"("key1", "key2")": "value"}
```

My code that saves and loads the file looks like this:

```
def Save(self):
    w=csv.writer(open("file.csv", "w"))
    for key, val in self.dictionary.items():
        w.writerow([key, val])
def Load(self):
    self.dictionary={}
    for key, val in csv.reader(open("file.csv")):
        self.dictionary[key] = val
        print self.dictionary.keys()
```

Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post runnable code that produces the output you say you're getting. You posted two methods, but they're useless without their surrounding class and its data.  Also, it looks like you've retyped the output... the difference between `'` and `"` really matters in a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed what kind of class might have those methods, and produced this output in `file.csv`:

```
"('key1', 'key2')",value
```

This looks fine to me.

Remember that the comma in your tuple has a different meaning in a CSV file: it is the field separator.  [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) had to escape or quote that comma or the CSV file would have contained *three* columns instead of the two you were expecting.  The typical escaping method is to wrap the cell's contents in quotation marks.

Finally, CSV files never store objects, they store strings (technically bytes, which `open` converts to strings).  Iterating over [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns a tuple of *strings* for each row in the CSV file, not of tuples or lists, or even integers.

To convert that string back into some other data type, you'll have to either pass it to a function like `int` or `float` (if you happen to know it should be an integer or floating-point number), or evaluate the string.  This a very dangerous thing to do, so ***don't* try to evaluate the string yourself**, and don't trust the built-in `eval` function to do it for you.  **Use the [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function**, which exists to do this as safely as possible.